# How to use memoize over sequence

Tags: functional-programming

```
let memoize (sequence: seq<'a>) =
    let cache = Dictionary()
    seq {for i in sequence -> 
         match cache.TryGetValue i with
         | true, v -> printf "cached"
         | false,_ -> cache.Add(i ,i)
    }
```

I will call my memoize function inside this function :

```
let isCached (input:seq<'a>) : seq<'a> = memoize input
```

If the given sequence item is cached it should print cached otherwise it will continue to add sequence value to cache.

Right now I have problems with types.

When I try to call my function like this :

```
let seq1 = seq { 1 .. 10 }
isCached seq1
```

It throws an error

```
"The type int does not match the type unit"
```

I want my function to work generic even though I return printfn. Is it possible to achieve that? And while adding value to the cache is it appropriate to give the same value to tuple?

eg:

```
| false,_ -> cache.Add(i ,i)
```

Comment: You'll need to show the body of `isCached`

Comment: it should be something like :

let isCached (input:seq<'a>) : seq<'a> = memoize input

Comment: Also edited my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is that your `memoize` function does not actually return the item from the source sequence as a next element of the returned sequence. Your version only adds items to the cache, but then it returns `unit`. You can fix that by writing:

```
let memoize (sequence: seq<'a>) =
    let cache = Dictionary()
    seq {for i in sequence do
           match cache.TryGetValue i with
           | true, v -> printf "cached"
           | false,_ -> cache.Add(i ,i)
           yield i }
```

I used explicit `yield` rather than `->` because I think that makes the code more readable. With this change, the code runs as expected for me.

Answer (score 0):

Tomas P beat me to the punch, but I'll post this up anyway just in case it helps.

I'm not too sure what you are trying to achieve here, but I'll say a few things that I think might help.

Firstly, the type error.  Your `isCached` function is defined as taking a seq of type 'a, and returning a seq of type 'a.  As written in your question, right now it takes a seq of type 'a, and returns a sequence of type unit.  If you try modifying the output specification to seq<'b> (or actually just omitting it altogether and letting type inference do it), you should overcome the type error.  This probably still won't do what you want, since you aren't actually returning the cache from that function (you can just add `cache` as the final line to return it).  Thus, try something like:

```
let memoize (sequence: seq<'a>) =
    let cache = Dictionary()
    for i in sequence do 
         match cache.TryGetValue i with
         | true, v -> printf "cached"
         | false,_ -> cache.Add(i ,i)

    cache

let isCached (input:seq<'a>) : seq<'b> = memoize input
```

All this being said, if you are expecting to iterate over the same sequence a lot, it might be best just to use the library function [Seq.cache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/seq.cache%5B't%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D).

Finally, with regards to using the value as the key in the dictionary...  There's nothing stopping you from doing that, but it's really fairly pointless.  If you already have a value, then you shouldn't need to look it up in the dictionary.  If you are just trying to memoize the sequence, then use the index of the given element as the key.  Or use the specific input as the key and the output from that input as the value.